# Error ArrayOutOfBoundException in 2D array

Tags: java

I get the error `ArrayOutOfBoundException: 15 at line 110`:

```
System.out.println(coordinates[k][l]);
```

When trying to run this code :

```
import TUIO.*;
TuioProcessing tuioClient;

int cols = 15, rows = 10;
boolean[][] states = new boolean[cols][rows];
String[][] coordinates = new String[cols][rows]; 
int videoScale = 50;

// these are some helper variables which are used
// to create scalable graphical feedback
int x, y, i, j, k, l;
float cursor_size = 15;
float object_size = 60;
float table_size = 760;
float scale_factor = 1;
PFont font;

boolean verbose = false; // print console debug messages
boolean callback = true; // updates only after callbacks



void setup(){
  size(500,500);
noCursor();

  noStroke();
  fill(0);

  // periodic updates
  if (!callback) {
    frameRate(60); //<>//
    loop();
  } else noLoop(); // or callback updates 

  font = createFont("Arial", 18);
  scale_factor = height/table_size;

  // finally we create an instance of the TuioProcessing client
  // since we add "this" class as an argument the TuioProcessing class expects
  // an implementation of the TUIO callback methods in this class (see below)
  tuioClient  = new TuioProcessing(this);

}
void draw(){
  // Begin loop for columns
  for ( k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    for ( l = 0; l < rows; l++) {

      // Scaling up to draw a rectangle at (x,y)
      int x = k*videoScale;
      int y = l*videoScale;

      fill(255);
      stroke(0);


for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) { 

 coordinates[i][j] = String.valueOf((char)(i+65)) + String.valueOf(j).toUpperCase();

  }
}
    /*  
      //check if coordinates are within a box (these are mouse x,y but could be fiducial x,y)
      //simply look for bounds (left,right,top,bottom)
      if( (mouseX >= x &&  mouseX <= x + videoScale) && //check horzontal
          (mouseY >= y &&  mouseY <= y + videoScale)){
        //coordinates are within a box, do something about it
       System.out.println(coordinates[k][l]); 
        //you can keep track of the boxes states (contains x,y or not) 
        states[k][l] = true;

        if(mousePressed) println(k+"/"+l);

      }else{

        states[k][l] = false;

      }

*/
      rect(x,y,videoScale,videoScale); 
    }
  }

   textFont(font,18*scale_factor);
  float obj_size = object_size*scale_factor; 
  float cur_size = cursor_size*scale_factor; 

  ArrayList<TuioObject> tuioObjectList = tuioClient.getTuioObjectList();
  for (int i=0;i<tuioObjectList.size();i++) {
     TuioObject tobj= tuioObjectList.get(i);
     stroke(0);
     fill(0,0,0);
     pushMatrix();
     translate(tobj.getScreenX(width),tobj.getScreenY(height));
     rotate(tobj.getAngle());
     rect(-obj_size/2,-obj_size/2,obj_size,obj_size);
     popMatrix();
     fill(255);
     text(""+tobj.getSymbolID(), tobj.getScreenX(width), tobj.getScreenY(height));
     System.out.println(tobj.getSymbolID ()+ " " + tobj.getX());

     if( ( tobj.getX()>= x &&  tobj.getX() <= x + videoScale) && //check horzontal
          (tobj.getY() >= y &&  tobj.getY() <= y + videoScale)){
        //coordinates are within a box, do something about it
       System.out.println(coordinates[k][l]); 
   }
rect(x,y,videoScale,videoScale);
}
}
// --------------------------------------------------------------
// these callback methods are called whenever a TUIO event occurs
// there are three callbacks for add/set/del events for each object/cursor/blob type
// the final refresh callback marks the end of each TUIO frame
// called when an object is added to the scene

/* void addTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {
  if (verbose) println("add obj "+tobj.getSymbolID()+" ("+tobj.getSessionID()+") "+tobj.getX()+" "+tobj.getY()+" "+tobj.getAngle());
}

 // called when an object is moved
void updateTuioObject (TuioObject tobj) {
  if (verbose) println("set obj "+tobj.getSymbolID()+" ("+tobj.getSessionID()+") "+tobj.getX()+" "+tobj.getY());
}

// called when an object is removed from the scene
void removeTuioObject(TuioObject tobj) {
  if (verbose) println("del obj "+tobj.getSymbolID()+" ("+tobj.getSessionID()+")");
}
*/

// --------------------------------------------------------------
// called at the end of each TUIO frame
void refresh(TuioTime frameTime) {
  if (verbose) println("frame #"+frameTime.getFrameID()+" ("+frameTime.getTotalMilliseconds()+")");
  if (callback) redraw();
}
```

Does it mean that it assigns a value at a greater place than the number of elements this array can contain ? How can I modify it ?

I can't find in the code where I specified the size of the array. I created it based on `cols` and `rows` (the 15 comes from there since when I modify it, say to 4, the error becomes `ArrayOutOfBoundException: 4`, but even with 1 there is an error so I don't get it) so I changed these values but I still get the error.

Thanks for your help

Comment: please show what you have at line "110" here.

Comment: The first two loops in draw() end at the end of the function - is this what you meant to do? (The third and fourth loop are inside the second one)

Comment: @kiruwka line 110 is the line I quoted right after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the variables `k` and `l` outside the following loop -

```
  for ( k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
    // Begin loop for rows
    for ( l = 0; l < rows; l++) {
```

Seems like k and l are defined in instance variable scope. After the above loop has ended the values of k is cols and the value of l is rows, and i am assuming that the length of coordinates is `(rows, cols)` .

Hence, you are getting the issue, when you try to print that within the `if` condition - `if( ( tobj.getX()>= x &&  tobj.getX() <= x + videoScale) && (tobj.getY() >= y &&  tobj.getY() <= y + videoScale))`

Maybe you want to print it before the loop for `k` and l`l variables are over. That is before the following lines -

```
      rect(x,y,videoScale,videoScale); 
    }  // <-- Here 'l' loop ends.
  } // <---- Here 'k' loop ends.

   textFont(font,18*scale_factor);
  float obj_size = object_size*scale_factor; 
  float cur_size = cursor_size*scale_factor;
```

Or maybe you do not want to end the `k` and `l` loop (the ones i mentioned in that start of this post) there? Did you miss commenting that part out?

Answer (score 1):

Value for variable `k` is 15 at the end of this for loop

```
for ( k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
// Begin loop for rows
     for ( l = 0; l < rows; l++) {

       // Scaling up to draw a rectangle at (x,y)
       int x = k*videoScale;
       int y = l*videoScale;

       fill(255);
       stroke(0);


        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) { 

            coordinates[i][j] = String.valueOf((char)(i+65)) +      String.valueOf(j).toUpperCase();

          }
        }
        rect(x,y,videoScale,videoScale); 
     }
   }
```

then you trying to access `coordinates` for index number `coordinates[15][11]` at this line :

```
System.out.println(coordinates[k][l]);
```

that's why you are getting Exception.

Hope this helps.